# How can I Call Azure SQL stored procedure using postman / Https

Tags: https, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I want to trigger a stored procedure using http request via logic app.

I dont want to use the default SQL Connector provided by the logic app.

Is there any way i can use the http request to call the SQL Scripts and stored procedure ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, there isn't. Do you think about call the another Azure Functions which run SQL Scripts and stored procedure in Logic app?

Comment: @LeonYue I want to call SQL endpoint directly using http not via any other azure function which is executing the SQL scripts

Comment: You can't, doesn't work that way. You need something else on top of the database to handle the http request.

Comment: Hi @DineshTripathi, I post it as answer. if it is helpful for you or you agree with it, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, the answer is no, there isn't a way can use the http request to call the SQL Scripts and stored procedure.

We can not run the SQL Scripts or stored procedure without SQL connector.

Like @Tim Mylott said that You need something else on top of the database to handle the http request.